# Internet explorer ajax response issue

Tags: ajax, json, internet-explorer, upload, fine-uploader

I have an file upload plugin (jQuery Fine Upload). With this plugin i upload images via AJAX, and from the response (JSON) generate preview images. This works fine in the major browsers, except all versions of Internet Explorer, because this sh... wants to open the JSON respone with .js extension. The event is fired when the file input will change. See the code below:

```
initFileuploader: function() {
    $('#imageUploadWrapper').fineUploader({
        request: {
            uuidName: 'uploadId',
            inputName: 'upload',
            endpoint: '/admin/model/media/image/upload', 
            params: {
                format: 'json'
            }
        },
        // debug: true, // ##### !!!!! #####
        autoUpload: true,
        responseJSON: true,
        deleteFile: {
            enabled: true,
            forceConfirm: true
        }
    }).on('complete', function(event, id, name, response) {

        var elem = $('.qq-upload-list li')[id];

        $(elem).prepend('<div class="previewContainer"></div>').addClass('cf');
        $(elem)
            .children('.previewContainer')
            .append($('<img src="/admin/model/media/image/view/tmp/'+response.result[0].name+'" class="previewItem"/>'));

    });
}
```

And this is the JSON response:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "version": "1.0",
    "code": 200,
    "result": [{
        "name": "08390ab5-0c1d-4801-bef9-7bfd5d446776.jpg",
        "type": "image\/pjpeg",
        "error": 0,
        "size": 845941
    }],
    "error": ""
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As specified in the documentation, your response's Content-Type header MUST have a value of "text/plain".  If your response's Content-Type is "application/json", as I presume yours is, you will run into the problem you are observing.